# Python: How to parse Timex3 into datetime or equivalent

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, sutime, timex

In my Python3 project, I use SUTime together with Stanford CoreNLP to retrieve normalized time expression in the Timex3 standard. I access CoreNLP using pycorenlp. How can I parse the resulting time expression in Timex3 (part of the TimeML standard) into a `datetime` or another temporal instance? I guess that `datetime` is probably not sufficient since it cannot represent dateranges

For instance, Timex3 expressions are:

`2017-11` referring to the whole month November

`2017-10-07` referring to the whole seventh day in November

I've already tried parsing them with the Python library `parsedatetime`, which is able to read almost any input containing a temporal expression, but the library is obviously not suited for the Timex3 format, i.e., it converts `2017-11` to a datetime of the current day (assuming it's November 2017):

`>>> dateparser.parse('2017-11')
datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 27, 0, 0)`

Isn't there a Python library for converting Timex3 expressions into datetime or something equivalent? Someone commented that `2017-11` cannot be converted into a datetime (as each only reflects a single points in time). But there's for example the `pandas`library, which contains date ranges as well.

Comment: `2017-11` is not enough to generate a date. The reason you are getting `27` because by default it takes the `sunday` of the week.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've updated my question correspondingly.